# Set margins to cater for large legend

Tags: r, plot, legend, legend-properties

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the height of a legend for a plot prior to setting the margins of the plot. I intend to place the legend below the plot below the x-axis labels and title.

As it is part of a function which plots a range of things the legend can grow and shrink in size to cater for 2 items, up to 15 or more, so I need to figure out how I can do this dynamically rather that hard-coding. So, in the end I need to dynamically set the margin and some other bits and pieces.

The key challenge is to figure out the height of the legend to feed into `par(mar)` prior to drawing the plot, but after dissecting the base codes for legend however, it seems impossible to get a solid estimate of the height value unless the plot is actually drawn (chicken and egg anyone?)

Here's what I've tried already:

1. get a height using the `legend$rect$h` output from the base legend function (which seems to give a height value which is incorrect unless the plot is actually drawn)
2. calculate the number of rows in the legend (easy) and multiply this by the line height (in order to do this, seems you'd need to translate into inches (the base legend code uses yinch and I've also tried `grconvertY` but neither of those work unless a plot has been drawn).

Another challenge is to work out the correct y value for placement of the legend - I figure that once I've solved the first challenge, the second will be easy.

**EDIT:**

After a day of sweating over how this is (*not*) working. I have a couple of insights and a couple of questions. For the sake of clarity, this is what my function essentially does:

step 1) set the margins

step 2) create the barplot on the left axis

step 3) re-set the usr coordinates - this is necessary to ensure alignment of the right axis otherwise it plots against the x-axis scale. Not good when they are markedly different.

step 4) create the right axis

step 5) create a series of line charts on the right axis

step 6) do some labelling of the two axes and the x-axis

step 7) add in the legend

Here are the questions

Q1) What units are things reported in? I'm interested in margin lines and coordinates (user-coordinates), inches is self explanatory. - I can do some conversions using grconvertY() but I'm not sure what I'm looking at and what I should be converting to - the documentation isn't so great.

Q2) I need to set the margin in step 1 so that there is enough room at the bottom of the chart for the legend. I think I'm getting that right, however I need to set the legend after the right axis and line charts are set, which means that the user coordinates (and the pixel value of an inch, has changed. Because of Q1 above I'm not sure how to translate one system to the other. Any ideas in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: you can generate the legend and assign it to a variable and not plot it - use the option `plot=FALSE`

Comment: Thanks user20650. I've tried that and I'm getting incorrect results if I call it before the plot is created. That's how I accessed $rect$h it's an output of using plot=FALSE with the legend function

Answer (score 0):

After another day of sweating over this here's what solved it mostly for me.

I pulled apart the code for the core legend function and compiled this:

```
#calculate legend buffer
cin <- par("cin")
Cex <- par("cex")
yc <- Cex * cin[2L] #cin(inches) * maginfication
yextra <- 0
ymax <- yc * max(1, strheight("Example", units = "inches", cex = Cex)/yc)
ychar <- yextra + ymax #coordinates
legendHeight <- (legendLines * ychar) + yc # in
```

Which is essentially mimicking the way the core function calculates legend height but returns the height in inches rather than in user coordinates. legendLines is the number of lines in the legend.

After that, it's a doddle to work out how to place the legend, and to set the lower margin correctly. I'm using:

```
#calculate inches per margin line
inchesPerMarLine<-par("mai")[1]/par("mar")[1]
```

To calculate the number of inches per margin line, and the following to set the buffers (for the axis labels and title, and the bottom of the chart), and the margin of the plot.

```
#set buffers
bottomBuffer = 1
buffer=2

#calculate legend buffer
legBuffer <- legendHeight/inchesPerMarLine

#start the new plot
plot.new()

# set margin
bottomMargin <- buffer + legBuffer + bottomBuffer
par(mar=c(bottomMargin,8,3,5))
```

The plot is made

```
barplot(data, width=1, col=barCol, names.arg=names,  ylab="", las=1 ,axes=F, ylim=c(0,maxL), axis.lty=1)
```

And then the legend is placed. I've used a different method to extract the legend width which does have some challenges when there is a legend with 1 point, however, it works ok for now. Putting the legend into a variable allows you to access the width of the box like `l$rect$w`. `trace=TRUE` and `plot=FALSE` stop the legend being written to the plot just yet.

```
ycoord <- -1*(yinch(inchesPerMarLine*buffer)*1.8)
l<-legend(x=par("usr")[1], y=ycoord, inset=c(0,-0.25), legendText, fill=legendColour, horiz=FALSE, bty = "n", ncol=3, trace=TRUE,plot=FALSE)
lx <- mean(par("usr")[1:2]-(l$rect$w/2))
legend(x=lx, y=ycoord, legendText, fill=legendColour, horiz=FALSE, bty = "n", ncol=3)
```

For completeness, this is how I calculate the number of lines in the legend. Note - the number of columns in the legend is 3. labelSeries is the list of legend labels.

```
legendLines <- ceiling(nrow(labelSeries)/3)
```